# Can a recursive query help in this date period "negation" task

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am working on some form of in-line (i.e. not UDF os SPROC) selection that would transform the returned date ranges to a form of "negative" date ranges. Here's the "source" set:

```
SELECT id, SDate, EDate
FROM table
ORDER BY SDate
```

Sample set:

```
1  01/05/2013  01/12/2013
2  01/13/2013  01/18/2013
3  02/05/2013  03/12/2013
4  07/08/2013  08/31/2013
```

Sought result (assume that we're interested in year 2013 only)

```
01/01/2013 01/04/2013
01/19/2013 02/04/2013
03/13/2013 07/07/2013
09/01/2013 12/31/2013
```

Am I on the right track trying to craft a recursive query using CTE? Anybody has SQL that can share?

Comment: what was missing in my shorter answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following handles inverting date ranges and correctly handles ranges that overlap the start and/or end of the target range.  **EDIT**: Updated to handle the case where no applicable ranges are found.

```
declare @DateRanges as Table ( Id Int Identity, SDate Date, EDate Date );
insert into @DateRanges ( SDate, EDate ) values
  ( '20130105', '20130112' ),
  ( '20130113', '20130118' ),
  ( '20130205', '20130312' ),
  ( '20130708', '20130831' ),
  -- Additional test data for ranges that overlap the target date range, or not.  
  ( '20100101', '20130101' ),
  ( '20131127', '20140102' ),
  ( '19990208', '20041118' ),
  ( '20601113', '20990101' );
select * from @DateRanges order by SDate;

declare @StartDate as Date = '20130101';
declare @EndDate as Date = DateAdd( day, -1, DateAdd( year, 1, @StartDate ) );
select @StartDate as [@StartDate], @EndDate as [@EndDate];

with SortedDateRanges as (
  -- Sort the date ranges so that we have a dense row number for later use.
  select SDate, EDate, Row_Number() over ( order by SDate ) as RN
    from @DateRanges
    where EDate >= @StartDate and SDate <= @EndDate ),
  PairedDateRanges as (
  -- Pair the adjacent date ranges and turn them inside out.
  select DateAdd( day, 1, L.EDate ) as SDate, DateAdd( day, -1, R.SDate ) as EDate
    from SortedDateRanges as L inner join
      SortedDateRanges as R on R.RN = L.RN + 1 )
  -- The result is all of inside out date ranges that are valid, i.e. don't end before they start...
  select SDate, EDate, 'Fill Gap' as Reason
    from PairedDateRanges
    where SDate <= EDate
  union
  --  ... plus any leading date range ...
  select @StartDate, DateAdd( day, -1, SDate ), 'Leading'
    from SortedDateRanges
    where RN = 1 and SDate > @StartDate
  union  
  --  ... plus any trailing date range ...
  select DateAdd( day, 1, EDate ), @EndDate, 'Trailing'
    from SortedDateRanges
    where RN = ( select Max( RN ) from SortedDateRanges ) and EDate < @EndDate
  union
  -- ... or we have nothing.
  select @StartDate, @EndDate, 'No Data'
    where not exists ( select 42 from SortedDateRanges )
  order by SDate;
```

Comment: Very similar to where I was going. Thanks for saving me the time!!

Comment: Could you update your answer (for completeness) to include edge case when source set is empty. I think this does it: `--  ... plus any leading date range ...
 SELECT @PeriodSDate, CASE WHEN cal.RN IS NULL THEN @PeriodEDate ELSE DateAdd( day, -1, cal.start_date ) END, 'Leading'
 FROM (SELECT @PeriodSDate AS start_date, @PeriodEDate AS end_date) AS def
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SortedDateRanges cal ON EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SortedDateRanges)
 WHERE 
  (RN = 1 AND cal.start_date > @PeriodSDate)
  OR
  (cal.RN IS NULL)`

Comment: @G.Stoynev - The answer has been updated to handle both an empty input table or a table with no date ranges in the target range.  It seemed easiest to just add another `UNION` that selects from nowhere.

Comment: A bit less elegant than t-clausen.dk's answer, but I guess this one is easier to understand.

Comment: I wouldn't call it less elegant - the trick to "turn adjacent ranges inside-out" is pretty neat. Without any speed tests, this one looked to have less overhead - no grouping and no EXISTS. Kept both for when I'll have time to try them under load.

Comment: @G.Stoynev I will call it less elegant, it is longer and slower (tested)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, I have been taking measurements and HABO's variant actually performs faster mainly because it eats up large chunks of dates in less CPU cycles. I could imagine a case where your script will perform better, but with a handful of source intervals HABO's version only needs a handful "inside-out" actions to derive the "opposite" intervals, where your version will keep probing 365 times doing EXISTS. In most cases I observed around 1600 ms for yours vs. low-two-digit for HABO's.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @t table (SDate date, Edate date)
insert @t values ('2013-01-01', '2013-12-20')

declare @year int = 2013

;with dates as
(
select dateadd(year, @year - 1900, 0) d
union all
select d + 1
from dates where
d < dateadd(year, @year - 1899, -1)
),
b as
(
select d, grp = d-row_number() over (order by d) from dates 
where not exists (select 1 from @t where dates.d between SDate and EDate)
)
select min(d), max(d) from b group by grp
option (maxrecursion 366)
```